# How to force github recognizing files as written in a specific language?

Tags: c++, c, github, header-files

I am writing a program in C which uses header files. These header files contain some structure declarations and, as C structures and C++ are pretty much the same, GitHub recognizes these files as C++ file, while I want them to be recognized as C files.

Is there a way to force GitHub recognizing header files as C files instead of C++ files?

Comment: Assuming that it succeeds, what difference of behaviour do you expect?

Comment: @Aram How about making an answer?

Comment: @Yunnosch I will.

Comment: _"C structures and C++ are pretty much the same"_ How so?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit enough for GitHub to not know if I'm writing C or C++ structures

Comment: Impressive, considering C++ doesn't _have_ structures ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh haha actually I never used C++. All I know is that when I type "C++ structure", I found a lot of results.

Comment: I'm sure you did. But it takes more than a two-word Google search to understand a language. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Github uses the linguist library to detect your code language. According to the [readme](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/README.md#using-gitattributes) in their git you need to create a .gitattributes if you don't have one and write in it the files/types you're matching to a language

So basically put in your .gitattributes

```
*.h linguist-language=C
```